# What is the need of OrderedDictionary, ListDictionary, and HybridDictionary?`

Tags: c#, .net, collections

What is the need of three different dictionaries- OrderedDictionary,ListDictionary and HybridDictionary when all of them perform similar functions?

None of them is sorted, and elements of the collection can be retrieved by key in all of them. So, what is the purpose of three different classes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In a nutshell:

- [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=VS.100).aspx) - Well, a dictionary.
- [`ListDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.listdictionary.aspx) - Used for small collections, typically less than 10 items
- [`HybridDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.hybriddictionary.aspx) - Used when the collection size is unknown (switches implementations depending on the size of the collection)
- [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) - The elements of an OrderedDictionary are not sorted by the key, unlike the elements of a [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx) class. You can access elements either by the key or by the index.

Comment: It is a good article...but what is the need of OrderedDictionary then, still concerns me??

Comment: @Novice - Sorry, missed that - adding more info now.

Comment: My guess is that the keys are ordered.

Comment: @Novice: the only thing that ordered dictionary offers is access to stored elements by index. I can't really come up with a quick example why it may be needed. In fact I never had a chance to use it in the code. Somehow it feels like a hack to me :)

Comment: nope...Keys are not ordered Tomas... I checked it myself through a simple program!!

Comment: Is there any significant difference then??

Comment: @Novice - I wouldn't say so, no. However the ability to use the index rather than the key makes it available to use in something such as a `for` loop.

Comment: Oh...Ok..Got it...Can we just ignore ListDictionary? For less number of elements we can make use of any of the other two also!!

Comment: @Novice - Well, remember it's always the tool specified for the job. If you for a fact that you will have 10 and under elements, use the ListDictionary. Remember, in order to provide the dual efficiency of the HybridDictionary, there will have to be overhead in determining the number of records / converting records in the dictionary. The rule of thumb is simple - use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: OrderedDictionary is a non-typed dictionary <object, object> that, and this is important, is guaranteed to maintain *insertion* order.  So if you need a Dictionary that maintains insertion order, not sorted by key, then you need to use the OrderedDictionary,

Answer (score 7):

To complement Kyle's answer:

OrderedDictionary allows retrieval by key and index (it uses a hashtable and and array internally) but has a bigger overhead per item

ListDictionary has a linked list as its internal structure, it does not perform well for insertion and retrieval by key but preserves the original insert order

HybridDictionary is a ListDictionary if the dictionary does not contain many items and converts to a Hashtable if the number of items reaches a speficic limit (I personally think you should use Dictionary<,> instead of it since C#2)

Comment: Not to forget the main difference between `ListDictionary` and `OrderedDictionary`, former doesnt preserve order, while latter does. `ListDictionary` naming is little confusing (and not needed in my opinion when you have hybrid version).