# ListDictionary Class vs List<Dictionary> C#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I've been search a lot about which one is better but I can't find something like a comparison.
What is the advantage of using the ListDictionary Class instead of using a List of Dictionary's?

I needed a List of dictionary in my project and i was searching when i found ListDictionary Class, but I can't find something like a post to know more about which one is better on x or y project (I'm currently working on .NET 4+ and WPF).

Comment: It is a .NET 1.1 class, added to alleviate the heft of a Hashtable.  Before generics were added in 2.0, so it is not type-safe.  That pretty much disqualifies it from modern source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ListDictionary` is very specific implementation of dictionary.

From the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.listdictionary?view=net-7.0

> Implements IDictionary using a singly linked list. Recommended for collections that typically include fewer than 10 items.

It is **not** a list of dictionaries, it is just a single plain dictionary. And of course it is not an equivalent of the `List<Dictionary>`, which actually is a list of dictionaries.

Conclusion: if you need many dictionaries placed into the list, then the `List<Dictionary>` is only option for you. The `ListDictionary` is totally unusable here.

Comment: I didnt know it. What's the difference between a ListDictionary and a Dictionary<TKey,TValue> or an old HashTable?

Comment: It might be that `ListDictionary` is poorly named - think of it as "Link-list backed Dictionary". https://stackoverflow.com/a/4623522/1043380

Comment: @TimSchmelter, in short: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is type-safe and fast even for large amounts of data. `ListDictionary` is not type-safe (works with `object` as key & value) and slow, especially if it contains many items. Bottom line: do not use `DictionaryList` in modern code, use `Dictionary<Tkey, TValue>, HashSet<T>` and so on instead.

Comment: @Serg: I see. It's one of those very old classes like HashTable which deserve an obsolete. I'm programming C# since .NET 1.1, so i wonder why i've never noticed that `ListDictionary`, i think there was never a real use-case for it.